# Create a mirror layout

Tags: android, android-layout, mirror

I'm building an application that works with mirrors, and my question is how can I create a mirror layout? I want to see all the textview's buttons.. on the layout like I'm watching from a mirror (Unreadable text..)

there is any way to do that?

Example of mirror text - [image: mirror..]

Comment: have a look here https://github.com/HannahMitt/HomeMirror

Comment: It's not related to my question.. I don't need any camera function..

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by setting `setScaleY(-1f)` on your layout.

So your main layout could look like this (immitating your example image):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/source_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="LOREM"
        android:textColor="#0084E2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/copy_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0084E2"
        android:scaleY="-1"
        android:text="LOREM"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The second `View` (or `ViewGroup`) must be an exact copy of your first one. You could create a custom `ViewGroup` that would automatically create a copy of a `View` and set its `scaleY` to `-1f`.